# Can I use a ZSink to commit offsets in Zio-Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, zio, zio-streams

I am learning ZIO integration with Apache Kafka, using the library `zio-kafka`. In the example on the [Github main project page](https://github.com/zio/zio-kafka), they use a `mapM` function to commit the offset of a chunk:

```scala
Consumer.subscribeAnd(Subscription.topics("topic150"))
  .plainStream(Serde.string, Serde.string)
  .tap(cr => putStrLn(s"key: ${cr.record.key}, value: ${cr.record.value}"))
  .map(_.offset)
  .aggregateAsync(Consumer.offsetBatches)
  .mapM(_.commit)
  .runDrain
```

However, IMHO, committing the offset is a terminal operation on the stream. Which is the difference in using a `ZSink`, instead?

```scala
Consumer.subscribeAnd(Subscription.topics("topic150"))
  .plainStream(Serde.string, Serde.string)
  .tap(cr => putStrLn(s"key: ${cr.record.key}, value: ${cr.record.value}"))
  .map(_.offset)
  .aggregateAsync(Consumer.offsetBatches)
  .run(ZSink.foreach(_.commit))
```